# JavaScript object data extraction get data from json.stringify to php

Tags: php, json

i am trying to post data using json.stringify
data like this

```
    <script>   
     $('.create-invoice').on('click', function()
            {
                grab_invoice_data();
                // Declare a variable
                var jsonObj = invoice_data;

                // Lets convert our JSON object
                var postData = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

                // Lets put our stringified json into a variable for posting
                var postArray = {json: postData};

                $.download("json.php", postArray, 'post');`enter code here`
            })

    </script>    

// php has like this 

   <?php
$arrData = json_decode($_POST['json'],true);
extract($arrData , EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");

$firstName = $arrData['name'];
$address1 = $arrData['address1'];
$address2 = $arrData['address2'];
$city = $arrData['city'];
$state = $arrData['state'];
echo $firstName;
echo $address1;
echo $address2;
?>
```

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\ASK_Soft\json.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: address1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ASK_Soft\json.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: address2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ASK_Soft\json.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: city in C:\xampp\htdocs\ASK_Soft\json.php on line 10
    .
    .
    thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after most try i got answer

```
   <?php
$arrData = json_decode($_POST['json'],true);
extract($arrData , EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");

$firstName = $arrData['name'];
$address1 = $arrData['address1'];
$address2 = $arrData['address2'];
$city = $arrData['city'];
$state = $arrData['state'];
echo $firstName;
echo $address1;
echo $address2;
?>
```

Thanking Lalit Sharma for this answer

Answer (score 1):

Write below code in your php script

```
$arrData = json_decode($youdata,true); // this will give you data in array format

extract($arrData , EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");
```

now you can..

```
echo $address1;
echo $address2; //and so on
```

Comment: To refer extract function pls go to http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php URL

Comment: you this line $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); "$data" variable

Comment: yout line json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); is giving you null data. it should given you a array

Comment: replace this file_get_contents('php://input') with $_POST['json']

Comment: replace this file_get_contents('php://input') with $_POST['json']

Comment: provide me your skype name will let you know there

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode`gives you an object so:

```
$firstName = $data->{'name'};
$address = $data->{'address'};
```

[php.net - json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)